# What is the difference between continuous deployment to continuous delivery?

Tags: terminology

I understand continuous integration as "orchestrating and continuously installing and/or upgrading an environment, or part of an environment, based on communally-maintained code".

*- my own definition.*

But what is the difference between continuous deployment to continuous delivery, if at all there is one and both are not just parallels.

Comment: Please avoid answering in the question, this site is not a forum for extended talk but aim at building a kind of knowledge base with minimal "noise". If you want to add an answer for things not already covered in other answers, do it in the duplicate target please, or suggest an edit to an existing answer.

Comment: Continous integration isn't about upgrading environments. It’s about integrating the changes a team make little and often. that’s usually merging changes together and running validation (eg compiles) and unit tests (eg runs possibly with synthetic tests and without deployment)

Comment: @Tensibai hello, did you rollback my edit because it was tonally wrong or because you felt it was not right to edit the question in its stage?

Comment: @JohnDoea as I said in my comment above, it sounded like a self answer and mostly an opinion, so it's only about the content, that's not a problem of tone (which was ok) or questions state (you can review the question to add more details if you feel the answers on the other question doesn't really answer what you were asking, but try to keep in line, if you change too much the question, it's better to ask another one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short:

`Continuous delivery is the capability to deploy the software to any given environment at a given point of time.`  The objective is to perform push-button deployments of any version of the software to any environment on demand.

Continuous Delivery is often conflicted with Continuous Deployment.  Any change the developer makes gets deployed all the way up to Production is *Continuous Deployment*

The referenced article will give some info:
[DevOps in nutshell](https://medium.com/@itsmesunil/devops-in-a-nutshell-fa0988132de7)

Comment: I assume "Continuous delivery" as an extreme form of "Continuous deployment" and that the difference is "standby and test" versus "directly to production" and that either can be "Continuous integration".

Comment: In DevOps i think everything is continuous.
**Continuous delivery** is a
process of deploying an application in any environment in an automated fashion and
providing continuous feedback to improve its quality. 
**Continuous deployment**, on the
other hand, is all about deploying an application with the latest changes to the production
environment.